# What equation used to implement the input level function of gimp in c?

Tags: gimp

I'd like to implement such as the level function of gimp by using c language.
What equation used to implement the input level function of gimp?

I just thought that the original image's value range is between 0~255.
but If I do adjust input level 0~206 from 0~255. then can I just do this?

adjusted pixel = Input pixel /255 * 206 ?

but I think this is not make sense, because the output range is more darker then before. how does the output image getting more brighter then before when I adjust input level?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to experiment. Create an image with a 256px-wide canvas. Create a Black-to-white RGB gradient across it. WIth the Pointer dialog (`Windows>Dockable dialog>Pointer`), it is easy to check that the pixels with horizontal coordinate `x` also have `R=G=B=x` (with minor variations).

Now apply the Levels tool. If you set the white point at 192 (255*3/4) then you can check that the pixels at `x` now have `R=G=B=(x*4)/3` (this shows that the function is linear). In the Levels tool you can also hit `Edit these settings at Curves` to enter the Curves tool. And you will see that the corresponding curve is actually a straight line.

PS: The middle handle is the "gamma". Experimentally, you put it where that input value will be the average of the black and white points.

Comment: What about the other pixels what over 192? are they just going to 255 at all?

Comment: Yes, they are, see the curve in Curves.